# How to pass a datatype like String, Date

Tags: java, types

Say I have a method declaration like:

```
private void someMethod(final String someKey, final Object dataType){
  // Some code
}
```

I want to call it like:

```
someMethod("SomeKey", String);
someMethod("SomeKey", Date);
```

I can it do it in different ways like declaring an int with different values representing the type, an enum, or the like.

But can I just pass the type itself?

**EDIT:**

To elaborate, I can do like:

```
someMethod("SomeKey", 1); // 1 = String
someMethod("SomeKey", 2); // 2 = Date
```

This doesn't look good.

Comment: Tell us the question, not the answer. Tell us what you're trying to accomplish, not what you think you need to do.

Comment: "But can I just pass the type itself?" - I think that was the question.

"I can it do it in different ways like declaring an int with different values representing the type, an enum, or the like."-So that you don't give me any alternatives.

Comment: Are you wanting to pass different types of objects to the same method, or are you wanting to pass information about a type to the method?

Comment: That's fine, but you're severly limiting the benefit you get from asking our community when you don't give context or say what you're actually trying to accomplish.  If we knew what you were trying to accomplish we might suggest a 3rd party library, we might list dangerous caveats, etc.  Maybe what you're trying to do is already supported by some Java library function and you don't know it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to pass the type of object as a parameter, you can do it by passing a `java.lang.Class`

i.e.

```
public void someMethod( String someKey, Class clazz ) {
    ... whatever
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

edit: incorporating Mark's comment.

You can call this like

```
someMethod( "keyA", Date.class );
someMethod( "keyB", String.class );
```

etc.

Comment: Expensive in terms of construction?  That's a class literal (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#251530).  It's a compile-time thing.  It's really hard to figure out what you're asking.  Could you describe what it is you want your method to do, even at a basic level?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the *instanceof* operator:
example:

```
private void someMethod(String someKey, Object dataType) {
    if (dataType instanceof String) {
        System.out.println("Called with a String");
    }
    else if (dataType instanceof Date) {
        System.out.println("Called with a Date");
    }
}
```

But this is bad style because you do not have type savety, it is better, to overload the method:

```
private void someMethod(String someKey, String dataType) {
    System.ount.println("Called with a String");
}

private void someMethod(String someKey, Date dataType) {
    System.ount.println("Called with a Date");
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need type safety here when you are not gonna process something that doesn't fall under any of your instanceof condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a type by "calling" .class on a class name, it will return an instance of [Class](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) that represents the type

```
private void someMethod(final String someKey, final Class<?> dataType){
// Some code
}

someMethod("SomeKey", String.class);
someMethod("SomeKey", Date.class);
```